# How do I update string value from inside a thread

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am coding a Xamarin.Forms cross platform app which works with users accounts. The problem is I get their username from my Database but it doesn't ever update the value of `public static string username = "";`

I am assuming it is because it's being ran inside a Thread or something to do with the WebRequest, I have done research for quiet a while but haven't been able to find a solution.

The method I am using to update their username is as follows

```
private void loadUserData()
    {
        username = "Test";
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/session-data.php?session_id=" + session);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
        {
            try
            {
                Stream stream = request.EndGetResponse(result).GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    string page_result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(page_result))
                    {
                        SupportMultipleContent = true // This is important!
                    };
                    var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    try
                    {
                        while (jsonReader.Read())
                        {
                            UserData userData = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserData>(jsonReader);
                            username = userData.username;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException readerExp)
                    {
                        string rEx = readerExp.Message;
                        Debug.WriteLine(rEx);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                string ex = exc.Message;
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }, null);
    }
```

When the url is opened it prints out the following line

> {"id":7,"username":"TestUser","name":"Test User","bio":"Hello World","private":0}

UserData contains the following code

```
class UserData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bio")]
    public string bio { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("private")]
    public int isPrivate { get; set; }
}
```

I also noticed the following error prints out, I tried googling around and haven't found any solutions I understand to fix this

> Error parsing positive infinity value. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: instead of writing down only the message of the exception, dump the whole exception (`Debug.WriteLine (exc)`): this will give you the whole stack trace of exception, includin the line of your code where the error happens: this will help you a lot in understanding what is your error. And in general, don't swallow exception as you are doing: your program is having an error, you just write it down and ignore it: how can you program proceed regularly if previous method did not do what expected?

Comment: I tried that and couldn't find any exceptions (the debug console https://pastebin.com/hCU4BxVn )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you are getting is a JSON.net one and happens during JSON deserialization, which means there is no problem with updating of the static variable, because the code never gets to that point (it ends on the `catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException readerExp)`).

This narrows your problem pretty well. There is very likely something wrong with the response you are receiving from the server. Put a breakpoint on the line `var jsonReader = ...` and check the contents of the `page_result` variable to see if they don't contain any unexpected characters. Potentially you can also dump the response into a JSON validator to confirm if it is actually valid (https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: That helped thanks! It also was because since it's async and its loading a webpage it already loads the next page before the value is updated.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Each variable is scoped in a memory dedicated only for the thread where its declaration is performed in, so, when you're accessing that variable from another thread, you're reading a copy of that in the memory of your other thread.
This copy is performed when the thread is synchronized with the another, and not always this is done just when you set the variable.
Therefore, you have to add `volatile` modifier to your variable declaration, which signs that the variable must be allocated and deallocated in a global synchronization scope.
Try declaring your variable such as this:

```
public static volatile string username = "";
```